# how to make a new action listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jbutton

this code move text from text field to label by adding action listener in move button 
now i want  delete implements action listener 
and generate my own action listener in new class and still make the button move the text

i don't how to really make  it please help :(

```
public final class Move extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private GridLayout gl;
    private JPanel jp;
    private FlowLayout fl;
    private JButton butMove;
    private JTextField txtFirst;
    private JTextField txtSecond;

    public void buildGUI() {
        this.setTitle("This is my moving JFrame");
        gl = new GridLayout();
        gl.setRows(2);
        gl.setColumns(1);
        this.setLayout(gl);
        jp = new JPanel();
        fl=new FlowLayout();
        jp.setLayout(fl);

        butMove = new JButton("Move");
        txtFirst = new JTextField("please enter a string",10);
        jp.add(butMove);
        jp.add(txtFirst);
        this.add(jp);

        txtSecond = new JTextField();
        this.add(txtSecond); 
        txtSecond.setEditable(false);
        //txtSecond.setBorder(new BorderFactory());
        // Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder();
        butMove.addActionListener(this);
        pack();
    }

    public GUI() {
        buildGUI();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String str = txtFirst.getText();
        txtSecond.setText("");
        txtSecond.setText(str);
        txtFirst.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create private inner class **inside** your class

```
private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String str = txtFirst.getText();
        txtSecond.setText("");
        txtSecond.setText(str);
        txtFirst.setText("");
    }
}
```

So this one is changed to:

```
butMove.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

Comment: aha ...Thanks So much :)

that was easy

Comment: why did u put add action listener on butMove ??

Comment: @MisakoKarasuma, because you did it that way. See you own code.

Comment: i know but i  wanted another way without using action listener ..!!

Comment: m sorry if i annoyed u  ..please forgive me

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) interface.

> An Action can be used to separate functionality and state from a component.

Here you could have as an inner class:

```
class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      txtSecond.setText(txtFirst.getText());
      txtFirst.setText("");
   }
}
```

Setting:

```
butMove.setAction(new MoveAction());
```

Comment: but setAction what is this method ??

Comment: It sets the `Action` for the control, but not only allows you to set the listener, but also icons &  enabled/disabled state. See the doc for [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html)

Comment: and what about the abstraction ??

Comment: You need to extend  `AbstractAction` as it implements `Action` - [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html)